# Simple terminal emulator (themable) with mark-as-copy with 'universal' $TERM

Tags: xterm, clipboard, terminal-emulator

I have a need for very simple terminal (no multiple tabs, no menu etc. - I use XMonad so splitting windows is not necessary as well). I tried to use xterm but unfortunately I need to be able to copy'n'paste while my middle mouse button does not work. I also tried to use st but it uses it's own termcap, which breaks many remote programs on any system it's not installed on.

(Any option to make xterm copy to clipboard on mark or st use TERM=xterm is also acceptable).

Comment: IIRC, you can use shift+insert to paste into xterm

Comment: @evilsoup I have troubles with copying from xterm - not pasting into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xterm.

If you want to copy to the clipboard instead of to the primary selection, set the `selectToClipboard` resource to true. In your `~/.Xresources`:

```
XTerm.vt100.selectToClipboard: true
```

If you have a mouse without a middle button, pressing both buttons at the same time emulates a middle click in most configurations.

You can use `xsel` or `xclip` to transfer between the selections:

```
xsel | xsel -b    # PRIMARY -> CLIPBOARD
xsel -b | xsel    # CLIPBOARD -> PRIMARY
```

Answer (score 0):

Select to copy is much older than wheel mice, so back in the day we would simultaneously click both mouse buttons to paste. This behavior is configurable through the `InputDevice` section of your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (or any file in the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory):

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    ## Enable two-button pasting
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "yes"
EndSection
```

I haven't done this in years though and [it turns out](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/874237) that there is now a conflict with Gnome that causes this approach to fail. If I understand correctly, it should still work for non-Gnome based environments.

If you are using Gnome or a Gnome derivative, use this command to activate two-button emulation of a middle click:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse \
  middle-button-enabled true
```

You should now be able to middle click using both buttons and keep using your favorite terminal-emulator.